# c#.NET LinQ - sorting subsets of a list of objects

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

I have a list of firms and their data (address, email, phone, active? (whether they are active in our system)). I can easily sort the list on the name but I need something a little different. The list has duplicates and I want to first sort by the name, then by active or inactive. I then want to mark the duplicates that are inactive so I can delete them.

The existing code is across multiple classes, but here is the jist (fixNullValues() simply returns an empty string if the excel cell is null):

```
for (int i = 2; i <= xlRange.Rows.Count; i++)
{
            firm = new Firm();
            string begCell;
            begCell = "B" + i;
            excelCell = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)excelWorksheet.get_Range(begCell, begCell);
            firm.acctNo = fixNullValues(Convert.ToString(excelCell.Value2));

            begCell = "C" + i;
            excelCell = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)excelWorksheet.get_Range(begCell, begCell);
            firm.name = fixNullValues(Convert.ToString(excelCell.Value2));

            begCell = "D" + i;
            excelCell = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)excelWorksheet.get_Range(begCell, begCell);
            firm.addy1 = fixNullValues(Convert.ToString(excelCell.Value2));

            begCell = "E" + i;
            excelCell = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)excelWorksheet.get_Range(begCell, begCell);
            firm.city = fixNullValues(Convert.ToString(excelCell.Value2));

            begCell = "AB" + i;
            excelCell = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)excelWorksheet.get_Range(begCell, begCell);
            if (Convert.ToString(excelCell.Value2).Equals("Active", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                firm.active = true;

            firmList.Add(firm);
```

Comment: Please provide the definition of "complete"? All properties have non-null values? More "complete" has properties of longer string values than "less" complete?

Comment: I updated the language on the question for clarity. I have ensured that no values will be null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var yourNewListWithoutDeleting = firmList.GroupBy(x => x.name)
                                         .SelectMany(x => 
                                             x.OrderByDescending(y => y.active)
                                             .Take(1)
                                         );
```

Comment: Thanks JDupont. To ensure I understand the code correctly, this groups the firms by name and then ensures "Active" is on the top and then selects that Active item and puts it into a new list. Sound right?

Comment: That's correct. Assuming you only have one active firm per name, this will get you an enumerable list of unique active firms. Hope it helps. Sorry I didn't add a description to it, I was in a hurry.

Answer (score 0):

See code below:

```
class Firm : IComparable<Firm>, IComparable
{
    string acctNo;
    string name;
    string addy1;
    string city;
    bool active;

    int completeness
    {
        get
        {
            return accNo.Length + name.Length + addy1.Length + city.Length;
        }
    }

    public int CompareTo(Firm other)
    {
        var c = name.CompareTo(other.name);
        if (c != 0)
            return c;
        c = active.CompareTo(other.active);
        if (c != 0)
            return c;
        return completeness.CompareTo(other.completeness);
    }

    public int CompareTo(object other)
    {
        return CompareTo((Firm)other);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Firm> sortFirms(IEnumerable<Firm> firms)
    {
        return firms.GroupBy(f => f.name).Select(g => g.OrderByDescending().First());
    }
}
```